# Как получить доступ к дочерним компонентам? Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2

Хочу создать универсальный компонент с фильтрами со структурой:

```
<filter-panel>
  <input>
  <component-input></component-input>
  <calendar></calendar>
</filter-panel>
```

Суть в том, что компонент с фильтрами должен собирать значения со всех вложенных фильтров и выполнять какой-либо свой метод. Компоненты-фильтры могут быть в любом количестве и порядке. Не хотелось бы вносить в разметку лишнего кода в каждый дочерний компонент, на примере события `(change)='childChange($event)`.

Получить дочерние компоненты и вставить в тело панели фильтров не составляет труда с помощью `<ng-content>`. Есть способ получить доступ к изменениям значений дочек?

Как вообще лучше всего будет реализовать данную задачу?

Comment: правильным решением будет реализация всех вложенных компонент с `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR`. Он позволит применять биндинг ngModel или formControl, который безупречно решает проблему оповещения `filter-panel` об изменении значений контролов

Answer (score 0):

Решить можно вашу задачу через динамические компоненты (сам реализовывал недавно). Вот [статья](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) по возможной реализации.

Сам делал так:

1. Добавляете в разметке своей компоненты следующее: `<ng-template #filterPlaceholder></ng-template>`. `#filterPlaceholder` - это ссылка на элемент
2. В теле компонента добавляете следующее:

   ```
   export class UgskTableComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
   @ViewChild('filterPlaceholder', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container;

   constructor(private componentResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

   ngAfterViewInit() {        
       let componentFactory: any;
       componentFactory = this.componentResolver.resolveComponentFactory(UgskTableInputFilterComponent);
       let component = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
       (<IUgskFilterComponent>component.instance).Label = 'Фильтр по фамилии';   
       (<IUgskFilterComponent>component.instance).Value = 'Иванов';   

       }
   }
   ```

   Реализация интерфейса:

   ```
   export interface IUgskFilterComponent {
       Value: any;
       Label: string;
   }
   ```

   Реализация компоненты фильтра

   ```
   export class UgskTableInputFilterComponent implements IUgskFilterComponent {
       @Input() public Value: any;
       @Input() public Label: string;

       constructor() { }
   }
   ```
3. Получение значений фильтра уже может быть путём сохранения ссылок на добавленные компоненты фильтра в родителе и по событию обращение к отрытым свойствам компонентов фильтров. Либо путём оповещения родителя об изменениях в дочерних элементах.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но это не совсем то, что я хотел. Мне кажется, что я нашел решение моей задачи здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802210/angular-2-child-component-events-broadcast-to-parent

Comment: И в документации оказывается это есть https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service . Как я раньше не заметил, не понимаю

Comment: хотя это тоже не подходит для моей задачи

Comment: Значит решение, надо искать самому :)